# Using preg_match to match weird characters

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to use preg_match to match all letters and numbers, but I've come across a weird letter that preg_match doesn't seem to match. How can I make it match? And what is that strange 'e' called? Are there more characters like that weird 'e' that I have to look out for?

```
<?php

$string = "pokémon";
preg_match("~(\w+)~", $string, $match);
print_r($match);

?>
```

**Result:**

Array ( [0] => pok [1] => pok )

**Need Result:**

Array ( [0] => pokémon [1] => pokémon )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'u' modifier (utf-8):

```
~(\w+)~u
```

<kbd>**[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/sN3eP9/1)**</kbd>